# Problem in my IF Statement, the Else is not working right

Tags: c++, if-statement

My simple code just receive the income from the user and calculate which bracket a user is in.

The IF statement is working fine, but when the user input some value with two decimals (ex. 100.50) value the code output the right tax and the else statement.

What can I do to fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

/**********************************************************************
 * This function will calculate which tax bracket a user is in.
 ***********************************************************************/
bool computeTax(float income)
{
   if (income >= 0.00 &&  income  <= 15100.00)
      cout << "10%" << endl;
   if (income > 15100.00 &&  income <= 61000.00)
      cout << "15%" << endl;
   if (income > 61300.00 &&  income <=123700.00)
      cout << "25%" << endl;
   if (income > 123700 && income <= 188450.00)
      cout << "28%" << endl;
   if (income > 188450.00 && income <= 336550.00)
      cout << "33%" << endl;
   if (income > 336550.00)
      cout << "35%" << endl;
   else
      cout << "Please enter a valid value" << endl;
   return 0;
}
int main()
{
   // configure the output to diplay money
   cout.setf(ios::fixed); // no scientific notation except for the deficit
   cout.setf(ios::showpoint); //always show the decimal point
   cout.precision(2); // two decimal for cents

   float income;
   cout << "Please enter your income: ";
   cin >> income;
   computeTax(income);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like `computeTax` really needs to return anything. It's return type should be `void`. Though it may be better to return the tax rate instead of printing it. You could easily print it outside the function. And returning it would allow you to use it in future calculations.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is your `else` is only an `else` for `if (income > 336550.00)`.  If that is false, then the else will trigger.  It doesn't matter if you have already taken case of it in another if statement.  What you need to do is chain all of the if statements together using `else if` so only ever on if statement, or the final else statement is executed.  That looks like

```
bool computeTax(float income)
{
   if (income >= 0.00 &&  income  <= 15100.00)
      cout << "10%" << endl;
   else if (income > 15100.00 &&  income <= 61000.00)
      cout << "15%" << endl;
   else if (income > 61300.00 &&  income <=123700.00)
      cout << "25%" << endl;
   else if (income > 123700 && income <= 188450.00)
      cout << "28%" << endl;
   else if (income > 188450.00 && income <= 336550.00)
      cout << "33%" << endl;
   else if (income > 336550.00)
      cout << "35%" << endl;
   else
      cout << "Please enter a valid value" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

---

Also note that `computeTax` can have a `void` return type so you don't have to have a useless `return 0;` at the end of the function.  Also, as pointed out by Jarod42, the name of the function is also wrong.  You call it `computeTax` but that isn't what you are doing.  You are displaying the tax rate so a name like `displayTaxRate` is more accurate.

Comment: @Jarod42 True.  Should probably be `displayTaxRate` instead.

Comment: Working perfectly! Thank you for help Nathan

Comment: @WagnerAntonelliFilgueiras You're welcome.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` statements are each interpreted in isolation of each other. You need to use `else if` for all your intermediate `if` statements before the final `else`, like so:

```
if(cond1)
{
     ...
}
else if(cond2)
{
    ...
} 
else if(cond3)
{
    ...
}
else // all other cases
{
    ...
}
```

Even if `cond1`, `cond2`, and `cond3` are mutually exclusive (like in your code), `else if` statements are still needed, because the `else` control path that is tied to `if(cond3)` will still be taken if `cond3` is false, even if `cond1` or `cond2` is true.

Answer (score 2):

*What can I do to fix it?*

Fix your if statements!  They need to be a cascading series of alternatives, using `else` before each `if`.

Further, you should avoid equality comparisons with floats (or doubles).

Finally, you don't need all of the comparisons if you take advantage of what has already been determined at each step of the cascade.

```
   if ( income > 336550.00 )
      cout << "35%" << endl;
   else if ( income > 188450.00 )
      cout << "33%" << endl;
   else if ( income > 123700.00 )
      cout << "28%" << endl;
   else if ( income > 61300.00 )
      cout << "25%" << endl;
   else if ( income > 15100.00 )
      cout << "15%" << endl;
   else if ( income > 0.00 )
      cout << "10%" << endl;
   else
      cout << "Please enter a valid value" << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well of course, you said

```
if (income > 336550.00)
    cout << "35%" << endl;
else
    cout << "Please enter a valid value" << endl;
```

and 100.50 > 336550.00 is false so the else part executes. What you are missing is that you should be using `if ... else if ... else`. Like this

```
if (income >= 0.00 &&  income  <= 15100.00)
    cout << "10%" << endl;
else if (income > 15100.00 &&  income <= 61000.00)
    cout << "15%" << endl;
else if (income > 61300.00 &&  income <=123700.00)
    cout << "25%" << endl;
else if (income > 123700 && income <= 188450.00)
    cout << "28%" << endl;
else if (income > 188450.00 && income <= 336550.00)
    cout << "33%" << endl;
else if (income > 336550.00)
    cout << "35%" << endl;
else
    cout << "Please enter a valid value" << endl;
```

The point about `if ... else if` is that as soon as one of the conditions is true then all the rest are ignored, which obviously is what you intended.

Comment: Yeah, that the point. I fixed. Working perfectly! Thank you for help John